# AutoLayout With Optional Content Sections (Need to find minimum vertical content size)

Tags: ios, objective-c, constraints, autolayout

I'm hoping someone can help me out with this problem. I have a very tall view with three different content section. For the sake of simplicity I will say that the UIView in Interface Builder is 1000px tall, each section is 300px tall, and there is a 50px margin between sections. Each section can be visible or hidden depending on the underlying data. So you could have 1,2, and 3 visible. Or 1 and 3. Or 1 and 2. Or just 3. Etc.....

In Interface Builder I set up all the constraints except for the vertical constraints that link the sections together and the constraints that link the sections to the top and bottom of the parent view. Those are all added at run time depending what sections are showing.

```
    //sample code

    //add constraint from top of view to first section
    NSLayoutConstraint* topConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:section1 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0 constant:0];
    [self.view addConstraint:topConstraint];

    //add constraint between sections
    NSLayoutConstraint* constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:section1 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:section2 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0 constant:50.0];
    [self.view addConstraint:constraint];

    //add constraint from bottom section to view
    NSLayoutConstraint* bottomConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:section2 attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0 constant:0];
    [self.view addConstraint:bottomConstraint];
```

When all three are visible, everything is fine. However, when I hide one, one or more of the elements on the screen is vertically stretched so that the content size now matches the size 1000px size of the parent view as it is drawn in Interface Builder. At least that's what I think is going on. I would instead expect the parent view to shrink to the size of the content.

Example: sections (300px each) 1 and 2 are showing with a 50px gap and section 3 is hidden. That means that the size of the content is 650px. I would expect AutoLayout to shrink the parent view to 650px. Instead, the view stays at the size drawn in Interface Builder which is 1000px and then AutoLayout stretches the sizes of the content sections to reach the 1000px. If I resize the view in Interface Builder that new size will be the rendered size. Regardless of the amount of sections showing.

I feel like I'm missing something simple but I've spent hours trying to figure this out. Any ideas?

**Edit**

Some clarifications. There are no height constraints on any of the sections because they can vary in height depending on the amount of data. I just used 300px each to simplify things. And I'm able to hide the sections instead of setting a zero height because in Interface Builder their are no constraints linking the sections. Those constraints are added through code at runtime because at runtime I know what needs to be linked to what. In the end. There is a solid link of vertical constraints from the top of the parent view to the bottom of the parent view. And none of the hidden sections contain vertical constraints.

**Edit 2**
If I defined a constraint for the height of the parent view, obviously I can modify the constant and manually set the size of view. Is there anyway to find the minimum size of a view based on dynamic content sizes and constraints?

Comment: This all depends on what constraints you have. Do your section views have a fixed height? Does you 1000 point tall view have a height constraint (or tied to the top and bottom of the superview)? Hiding a view doesn't remove its constraints, so you might need to give them a 0 height, or remove them entirely instead.

Comment: See the edit in the original question. I clarified a few things. I hope this helps.

Comment: That does clarify some, but it would be much more helpful to see the constraints you are adding in the example you have in your question.

Comment: So is self.view in these constraints the controller's self.view? Or, if not, does that view have a height constraint? The constraints you're showing are by themselves, ambiguous. How are you defining the heights of section1 and section2?

Comment: Yes, self.view is the controller's self.view and it's doesn't have a defined height. In fact, nothing has a defined height. I was under the impression that the content of the labels and tableViews would resize their own heights dynamically. Then their combined height would set the height of self.view. Or that's what I was hoping for.